# Find the equation of the plane that is perpendicular to $3x+2y-4 = 0$ and goes through A(1;0;3)

Tags: calculus, geometry

First I tried to find the direction vector:

$\vec{n} = (3;2;0)$

Another point from that vector would be $(3;2;0)\cdot 0 = (0;0;0)$

I tried to get the slope using:

$$\frac{3-0}{2-0}= 3/2$$

I need to get a line that is perpendicular to this one, so the slope of that line has to be $-2/3$.

But what do I do next?

Also, I could only calculate the slope here because the z coordinate is zero. How do you calculate the slope for 3D vectors?

Comment: $A+sn+te_3$ with $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $e_3=(0,0,1)$

Comment: There is not a single plane perpendicular to a given plane passing through a point.

Answer (score 0):

Your plane is described by an equation like $ax+by+cz=d$ and you know that one of its points is $(1,0,3)$. Therefore, $a+3c=d$. Also, you know that it is perpendicular to the plane $3x+2y=0$. (No, it is not a typo. The planes $3x+2y=0$ and $3x+2y=4$ are parallel.) This is the same thing as saying that $(a,b,c)$ and $(3,2,0)$ are orthogonal, that is, that $3a+2b=0$. So, if you pick two numbers $a$ and $c$ and if you define $b=-\frac32a$ and $d=a+3c$, then the plane $ax+by+cz=d$ (that is, the plane $ax-\frac32ay+cz=a+3c$) is a solution of your problem (and every solution can be obtained by this process).

Answer (score 0):

The parametric form of the line $3x+2y-4=0$ is $$x=t, y=\dfrac{-3}{2}t+4, z=0.$$ So this line is parallel to the vector $<1, \dfrac{-3}{2}, 0>$. The plane now passes through the point $(1, 0, 3)$ and is perpendicular to the vector $<1, \dfrac{-3}{2}, 0>$. So its equation is $$1.x+\dfrac{-3}{2}y+0.z=1.1+\dfrac{-3}{2}.0+0.3=1.$$ Or $2x-3y=2$.

Comment: $3x+2y-4=0$ is a plane, not a line.

Comment: I interpreted it as a line on the $xy$-plane.

Answer (score 0):

A plane passing though $A$ has equation:
$$ax+by+cz=ax_A+by_A+cz_A=a+3c.$$
Any plane containing the perpendicular line to the plane $3x+2y-4=0$ passing though $A$ solves the problem. It contains this perpendicular line if and only if its normal vector $\vec n\vphantom{n}'(a,b,c)$ is orthogonal to $\vec n$, i.e. if and only if $\;3a+2b=0$. The solutions are given by 
$$a=2\lambda,\quad b=-3\lambda\qquad(\lambda\in\mathbf R)$$
so the solution plane has equation
$$\lambda(2x-3y)+cz=2\lambda+3c\iff\lambda(2x-3y-2)+c(z-3)=0.$$

This is a sheaf of planes, and the planes $2x-3y-2=0$ and $z-3=0$ is a basis of this sheaf.

Answer (score 0):

One more:

Normal of the plane: $3x + 2y - 4 = 0$ is

$\vec{n} = (3, 2, 0)$.

We are looking for a plane with a normal perpendicular to this normal.

Vector $\vec{N_1} = (0, 0, 1)$ is perpendicular (scalar product with $\vec{n}$  equals $0$)

Another perpendicular choice is $\vec{N_2}$ = $(2, -3, 0)$,  also perpendicular to $\vec{N_1}$.

A general normal vector of the desired plane:

$\vec{N}$= $\alpha \vec{N_1}$ + $\beta \vec{N_2}$.

A plane passing through $A(1, 0, 3)$ is described by:

$(\vec{r} - (1, 0, 3)) \cdot ( \alpha \vec{N_1} + \beta \vec{N_2})$ = $0$.

Special choice: $\beta$ = $0$,  $\alpha \ne 0$.

Then

$(x - 1, y, z - 3) \cdot (0,0,1)$ = $0$;

$z = 3$.

This plane is parallel to the $x -, y - $ plane through $z=3$.